# Как сделать clip-path (-webkit-) кроссбраузерным?

Tags: html5, сss3, clip-path

На [Toster](https://toster.ru/q/348899) задали вопрос как создать такую вёрстку (скрин):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разумеется я это сделал (топорно):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section {
  display: table;
  width: 950px;
  min-width: 950px;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: auto;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 90px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
.wrapper2 {
  margin: -46px 91px;
}
.wrapper3 {
  margin-left: 180px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper1">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper3">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Но больше всего раздражает что это не кроссбраузерно , каким образом можно добиться что бы пример работал везде ?

> http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/OXKQVo?editors=110

Comment: Чтобы везде (на большинстве браузеров), то вырезать многоугольники из маета и так их и вставлять с margin: -xx px; или абсолютах.

Вот еще пример неплохой: http://codepen.io/gpyne/pen/iElhp?editors=1100

Comment: Лена ты ж была на toster ? видела там требование ? но канечно чисто символически - но я рискнул

Comment: я видела требования и говорю "Чтобы везде (на большинстве браузеров) ... " то только так. 
С clip-path http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path.

Comment: спасибо Лена , спрошу ещё у америкосов , мож они что то новое откроют для меня - поделюсь потом

Comment: О, а за это спасибо, было бы интересно узнать)

Comment: я вам на github отпишусь потом Лена

Comment: ок), но можно и сюда. Думаю многим было бы полезно и интересно узнать решение.

Comment: Лена сюда вообще обязательно  отпишусь , но премию через 2 дня предложу

Comment: Это можно сделать и без clip-path. Тут даже где-то вопрос был.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сделал, без `clip-path`, за счет наклоненных субэлементов.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #fb1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #707020;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
a.btn:hover {
  background-color: #bada55;
}
a.btn:active {
  background-color: #707020;
}

.hexagon {
  background-color: #888;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  width: 190px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.hexagon.bg-1 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/1'); }
.hexagon.bg-2 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/2'); }
.hexagon.bg-3 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/3'); }
.hexagon.bg-4 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/4'); }
.hexagon.bg-5 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/5'); }
.hexagon.bg-6 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/6'); }
.hexagon.bg-7 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/7'); }
.hexagon.bg-8 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/8'); }
.hexagon.bg-9 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/9'); }

.hexagon > .face1,
.hexagon > .face2 {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.hexagon > .face1:before,
.hexagon > .face2:before {
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  height: 220px;
  left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 220px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.hexagon > .face1        { transform: rotate( 60deg); }
.hexagon > .face1:before { transform: rotate(-60deg); }
.hexagon > .face2        { transform: rotate(-60deg); }
.hexagon > .face2:before { transform: rotate( 60deg); }

.hexagon:after,
.hexagon > .face1:after,
.hexagon > .face2:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 50, 100, 0.5);
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.hexagon > .body {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.hexagon-body {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: normal;
}
.hexagon-body > p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px #000;
}

.hexagon-row {
  margin-top: 54px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.hexagon-row.four  { margin-left: 0; }
.hexagon-row.three { margin-left: 97px; }
.hexagon-row.two   { margin-left: 194px; }
.hexagon-row.one   { margin-left: 291px; }

.hexagon-container {
  padding: 6px 0 54px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-container">
  <div class="hexagon-row four">
    <div class="hexagon bg-1">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт квартир</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hexagon bg-2">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт коттеджей и домов</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hexagon bg-3">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт небоскребов и дворцов</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hexagon bg-4">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт коммерческих и производственных помещений</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon-row three">
    <div class="hexagon bg-5">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hexagon bg-6">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hexagon bg-7">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon-row two">
    <div class="hexagon bg-8">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hexagon bg-9">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon-row one">
    <div class="hexagon bg-3">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon-row four">
    <div class="hexagon bg-1">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт квартир</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hexagon bg-2">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт коттеджей и домов</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hexagon bg-3">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт небоскребов и дворцов</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hexagon bg-4">
      <div class="face1"></div>
      <div class="face2"></div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="hexagon-body">
          <p>Ремонт коммерческих и производственных помещений</p>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Заказать</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Текст следующей секции</p>
```

[Или посмотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/0n9sk1q4/)

---

```
<div class="hexagon bg-1">
  <div class="face1"></div>
  <div class="face2"></div>
</div>
```

`.hexagon` здесь - прямоугольник размерами `190px*110px`. Где:

- `190px` - ширина шестигранника от одной грани до другой
- `110px` - длина грани шестигранника ("толщина" прямоугольника)

`.face1` и `.face2` - прямоугольники таких же размеров, но наклоненные - `.face1` вправо на 60 градусов, `.face2` - влево.

```
.hexagon.bg-1 { background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/220/220/nightlife/1'); }

.hexagon > .face1,
.hexagon > .face2 {
  background: inherit;
}
.hexagon > .face1:before,
.hexagon > .face2:before {
  background: inherit;
}
```

`.face1` и `.face2` наследуют свойство `background-image` от `.hexagon` за счет `background: inherit`.

```
.hexagon > .face1,
.hexagon > .face2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hexagon > .face1:before,
.hexagon > .face2:before {
  height: 220px;
  left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 220px;
}
.hexagon > .face1        { transform: rotate( 60deg); }
.hexagon > .face1:before { transform: rotate(-60deg); }
.hexagon > .face2        { transform: rotate(-60deg); }
.hexagon > .face2:before { transform: rotate( 60deg); }
```

`:before`-блоки - квадратные c размером в `220px`, выровненные по центру относительно блоков размером `190px*110px`. `220px` - это расстояние от одного угла шестигранника до противоположного. Таких размеров оптимально брать и изображение на фон.

`:before`-блоки заполняются тем же фоном, что и `.hexagon`, но фон специально смещается так, чтобы устранить эффект поворота блока. Например, `.face1` поворачивается на 60 градусов вправо, а фон для него - на 60 градусов влево.

Таким образом при наложении фона `.hexagon` на фон `.face1` и `.face2` не видно искажений и швов (швы смягчаются за счет свойства `backface-visibility: hidden;`).

```
.hexagon {
  z-index: 0;
}
.hexagon > .face1,
.hexagon > .face2 {
  z-index: -1;
}
.hexagon > .face1:before,
.hexagon > .face2:before {
  z-index: -2;
}
.hexagon:after,
.hexagon > .face1:after,
.hexagon > .face2:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 50, 100, 0.5);
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

`:after`-блоки затемняют и придают определенный оттенок изображению на фоне.

```
.hexagon > .body {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.hexagon-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Контент в шестиграннике размещается в `.body > .hexagon-body`.

`display: table` и `table-cell` выравнивают контент по нижнему краю `.hexagon`. Если посмотреть ваш пример, можно заметить - кнопки расположены в одну линию, а многострочный текст идет от кнопки вверх.

> Этого же эффекта можно добиться, задав для `.hexagon-body` абсолютное позиционирование и разместив его по нижнему краю. В этом случае уже не понадобится контейнер `.body`, но в этом случае рендер контента будет происходить вне основного потока, плюс изменится принцип выравнивания контента в экстремальном случае.
>
> Если при `table-cell` текст занимает столько строк, что не помещается в отведенное ему пространство до верха `.hexagon` - весь контент начинает выравниваться от верхнего края вниз. Это видно в моем примере - у крайнего правого шестигранника кнопка расположена ниже. При `position: absolute` текст продолжит уходить вверх, кнопка будет оставаться на месте.

```
.hexagon-row {
  margin-top: 54px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.hexagon-row.four  { margin-left: 0; }
.hexagon-row.three { margin-left: 97px; }
.hexagon-row.two   { margin-left: 194px; }
.hexagon-row.one   { margin-left: 291px; }
```

`margin-top` корректирует вертикальное выравнивание каждой новой строки с шестигранниками.

`white-space: nowrap;` гарантирует, что шестигранники не будут переноситься на следующую строку при нехватке ширины у контейнера.

Номерные классы означают количество шестигранников в строке. Используются для выравнивания по-горизонтали. С такими классами можно строить сетки не только неизбежно сужающиеся, но любых форм (видно в примере).

```
.hexagon-container {
  padding: 6px 0 54px;
}
```

Корректируем отступ до верхней строки и после нижней.

Comment: Встройте сниппет прямо в ответ, с помощью кнопки `<>`

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку, не знал, что для сниппетов есть встроенная песочница. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: решение очень интересное, мне система не даёт выбрать ваш ответ лучшим и присудить вам 200 балов

Comment: через 9 часов награда будет ваша Виталий

Comment: и ради этого я досконально (в пределах разумного) изучил SVG